# Lookup, concatenate and remove items in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists of lists that looks like this:

```
[[[1], [’apple’], [’AAA’]]
[[2], [’banana’], [’BBB’]]
[[3], [’orange’], [’CCC’]]
[[4], [’pineapple’], [’AAA’]]
[[5], [’tomato’], [’ABC’]]]
```

Probably the wrong terminology, but: I want to find duplicates in the third column, add that row's second column item to the first instance of the duplicates, and then remove the duplicate row.

So using the example: I want to iterate through the list, find the duplicate value ‍`'AAA'`, add `'pineapple'` after `'apple'` and remove the (second level) list containing the second instance of `'AAA'`.

The list I want to end up with should look like:

```
[[[1], [’apple’, 'pineapple'], [’AAA’]]
[[2], [’banana’], [’BBB’]]
[[3], [’orange’], [’CCC’]]
[[5], [’tomato’], [’ABC’]]]
```

I tried the following but I can't figure out how to do this..

```
seen = set()
for l in final:
    if l[2] not in seen: # TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
        # Here I want to add value to first instance
        seen.add(l[2])
        # Remove list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you're asking for... but I seriously wonder whether you can't change your data structure. It's strange and hard to work with!

```
newList = []
lookup = {}
for l in final:
    if l[2][0] not in lookup:
        lookup[l[2][0]] = l
        newList.append(l)
    else:
        lookup[l[2][0]][1].append(l[1][0])

print newList
```

The reason you were getting the `TypeError` is you that you were doing this `l[2]` instead of `l[2][0]`. Remember, `l[2]` is a list. What you want is to grab the item inside that list (index `0` in this case) and check if *that* is in `lookup`. The `lookup` replaces the `seen` set implemented in your example because it can also help get back the entry that a duplicate `l[2][0]` would correspond to, since your data structure currently isn't set up to do something like `final['AAA']`. However, this isn't very ideal and I'd heavily recommend you do something about changing this, if possible.

#### Something else to think about...

Currently, because your items are all essentially lists within lists, the current algorithm will essentially change the nested objects (lists) you were working with, because of object mutability. This means that while `final` would contain the same objects it did originally, those objects will have changed (in this case with `['apple', 'pineapple']`).

If you want to prevent that from happening, look into using the `copy` module. Specifically, using the `deepcopy` method to copy all objects (even through the nesting).

#### Edit:

***w0lf's version*** (Improved readability)

```
newList = []
lookup = {}
for l in final:
    row_no, fruit, code = l
    unique_id = code[0] # because `code` is a one element list
    if unique_id not in lookup:
        lookup[unique_id] = l
        newList.append(l)
    else:
        lookup[unique_id][1].extend(fruit)

print(newList)
```

Also note: He remembered to do `print(newList)` instead of `print newList` for Py3k users. Since the question is tagged for Python 3, that's the way to go.

Comment: one thing that would help readability a bit: `for row_no, fruit, code in final:` instead of `for l in final:`

Comment: Also, I believe you do not need the `seen` set. You already have the `lookup` dictionary and you could just as well do `if l[2][0] not in lookup:`

Comment: @w0lf Thanks, editing the post now. Hah, can't believe I let that slip!

Comment: Don't worry; it can happen to anybody. :) Regarding my first comment, here's a version I arrived at: http://ideone.com/qg8UhO. I find this one more readable, but it's just my subjective opinion.

Comment: @w0lf Nah, don't even go there with the 'subjective' opinion! ;) We both know your version improves readability. With your permission, I'd gladly update the answer.

Comment: Sure, please post it if you like it!

Answer (score 0):

List is unhashable type, i.e you cannot add it (as is) to data structures that uses hash maps (like python dictionary or set). but strings are hashable.
I'd do

```
seen.add(str(ls[2]))
```

This will solve the TypeError